# Why does the map legend not update in print composer?

Tags: qgis, layouts

I'm having trouble with the QGIS map composer:

If I change the map in QGIS and reopen the map composer and click on update, the legend elements DON'T update! For example: Before one certain country was filled with blue, now with violet. The little box in the legend showing the color of that map element doesn't change. It stays blue.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is a bug.  You can try a dev or nightly build or wait until version 2.0 is released.

`Map Composer doesn't refresh the legend`

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5480

Answer (score 0):

This issue still hasn't been fixed in version 2.4.  The colours and values of legend items for rasters do not update in print composer if changed from their original settings.